# Javadoc: line breaks without HTML-tags?

Tags: java, netbeans, comments, javadoc

*Sorry for a probable FAQ kind of question, but I just can't find the answer.*

As far as I remember Eclipse, a blank line in a Javadoc comment is displayed (in in-source Javadoc popups) as a line break (with extra vertical spacing).

In Netbeans, however, this is not the case.

**Can I configure Javadoc to interpret a blank line as a line break?**

**Additional question: Can I override default Netbeans behavior (related to this) for in-source Javadoc popups?**

What I'm talking about is:

### Source

```
/**
 * Paragraph One
 *
 * Paragraph Two
 */
 void someMethod() { }
```

### Eclipse interpretation

```
 Paragraph One

 Paragraph Two
```

### Netbeans interpretation

```
 Paragraph One Paragraph Two
```

Comment: Many of these answers are now out-of-date (superseded) by NetBeans8.2, see the answer from @fujy below, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 103):

It has nothing to do with Netbeans. I suspect you are looking at the source code in one case and the output of Javadoc in the other case. Newlines are not significant in HTML: *ergo* the output will not show them. If you want a newline use a `<p>` or a `<br>`.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, Eclipse *does* consider blank lines as paragraphs. So my assumption is that it *has* to be possible to achieve this by some javadoc configuration (Netbeans or without).

Comment: Eclipse shows you the source code however it is formatted. Netbeans 6.9.1 shows you the source code too, ditto, i.e. it doesn't ignore line breaks either. However if you are looking at the *output* of Javadoc by any means if would be incorrect for that means *not* to ignore line breaks.

Answer (score 51):

I'm not sure if this helps for OP's case, however I put `<pre></pre>` around my document so netbean does not mess up my formatting. So it will look like

```
/**
 * <pre>
 * Paragraph One
 *
 * Paragraph Two
 * </pre>
 */
```

This is closest I get to showing new lines in text format. I'm using NetBeans 7.1.2. This way using `code format` option will not reformat the document. Showing doc in hints is still formatted.

Update: in Netbeans 8.x there is an option in code formatting to disable formatting comments.

Comment: This is good but there is one drawbacks.  It breaks soft-wrapping. It becomes noticeable for long line of text. So e.g. if your IDE shows "tooltips" like javadoc, it will become as long as the line would until end of the line forcing you to scroll right.

Comment: @GreenMarty, which one? solution for version 7 or 8? For 8 you will not need to use pre tags anymore. for 7 you will technically need to break lines to the width of your code, normally dictated by company (for mine is 160 char) which means you will still see the entire doc as its font is smaller than the code itself.

Anyway, I stopped using netbeans around 2018 and switched to InteliJ which doesn't have this issue (doesn't mean it does not have other issues ;) )

Comment: I use latest IntelliJ as well.  When i write long line within `<pre></pre>` tag i get long line in rendered javadocs "tooltip".  Line just never wraps AFAIK.   I take it it's meant to be that way so e.g. `{@code...}`  doesn't get wrapped  in "tooltip" view.

Comment: @GreenMarty that is correct, use of pre meant to stop reformatting the doc and show it the way it is. so if you need the doc to go to next line, you will need to put line-breaks in it yourself.

Comment: I understand that i thought you said, it doesn't work that way in Intellij Idea so i replied it does not wrap in Intellij either.

Answer (score 16):

There is already an option in `NetBeans` - tested on version 8.2 - that allows you to preserve new lines in your comments, and/or add a `<p>` tag to your `Javadoc` if needed

- Just from the `Tools` menu, chose `Options`
- Go to `Editor` tab, then `Formatting` tab
- In the `Language` menu chose `Java`, and in `Category` menu chose `Comments`
- Check the `Preserve New Lines` checkbox in the `General` section if you want to preserve new lines in your comments. **This will preserve new lines without adding `<p>` tag**
- Check `Generate "<p>" on Blank Lines` checkbox in the `Javadoc` section **if you  also want to add `<p>` tag**.

[image]

Comment: Definitely the best answer w.r.t. NetBeans 8.2. Easy. But you should please edit it to add that it only actually kicks in when you perform Format on the code (with existing line-breaks). One has to be careful, if there are already some `<p>` in there by hand it can sometimes add double `<p>``<p>` the first time.  Thereafter it works as expected.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with you, HTML doesn't belong in source-code. Sadly, I didn't find much help Googling around for this. It's actually quite easy to implement.

Here's the custom Doclet that you can compile and use:

```
import com.sun.javadoc.*;
import com.sun.tools.doclets.standard.*;

/**
 * Formats text-only comments with HTML.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("restriction")
public final class TextDoclet {
    private static final Pattern NEWLINE_REGEX = Pattern.compile("\\n");
    private static final String BR = "<br/>\n";

    public static boolean start(RootDoc rootDoc) {
        for ( ClassDoc classdoc : rootDoc.classes())
            classdoc.setRawCommentText(formatText(classdoc.getRawCommentText()));

        return Standard.start(rootDoc);     
    }

    private static String formatText(String text) {
        return NEWLINE_REGEX.matcher(text).replaceAll(BR);
    }
}
```

An example of how to invoke it using javadoc:

```
javadoc -docletpath ~/project/text-doclet/target/text-doclet-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -doclet com.myorg.textdoclet.TextDoclet -sourcepath ~/project/myapp/src/main/java -subpackages com.myorg.myapp
```

Answer (score 2):

JavaDoc displays the way the CSS styles have been defined. You could edit the CSS styles associated with paragraph tags to do this:

```
p {
    line-height: 25px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm sure that Netbeans doesn't interpret a blank line as a paragraph at all (see "Netbeans interpretation" in my question). I mean: you can only define line spacing if you have lines.

Comment: Hmm. I saw that. But not really sure if Netbeans provides an option to edit this.

Answer (score 2):

This is a pseudo-solution
(which sadly affects only generated javadoc, but does **not** affect Netbeans' in-source javadoc display).

Specify a stylesheet which contain the following:

```
div.block {
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what Eclipse is doing here, but if you want this behavior in general (not only an IDE), you may have to create a new Doclet (which may be based on the default HTML doclet) instead, there inserting a `<p>` at every empty line or such.