# Mouse hovering on function in code does not show paragraph breaks

Tags: javadoc

No paragraphs or line breaks rendered ? ... maybe no html at all ? Oh well, @param, @return and @author do render....

Simply, when I write my lil help functions I always write down its "javadoc" (for lack of specific term for Javascript).
For example:

```
/**
* Ok, let's make some changes to an object and see that they stick or get dropped according to the button we press.
* <br> And why in the friging hell VSC won't honor html page breaks here ? <br> or bold <b>Or here ? <p>
* @param none
* @return nothing
*/

async testChangingObjectValues()
{
     // do some stuff changer
}
```

and now if I just hover the mouse over testChangingObjectValues() all i see is just a long sausage of text, no nice paragraph or line breaks.

Is there a request to fix that ?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javadoc: line breaks without HTML-tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077382/javadoc-line-breaks-without-html-tags)

Comment: Yeah, it does... I used the suggestion to add a blank line wherever I want to create a new paragrah. Thank you !